# Equivalence of Riemann integral definition.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Decide if the following definitions of Riemann integrability are equivalent.
>
> **Definition 1:**
>
> We say that $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is integrable if there exists an $L$ such that for any sequence of tagged paritions $P_n$ of $[a,b]$ satisfying $\|P_n\|\to 0$, we have that for given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $n\ge n_0$ implies $$|S_P(f)-L|<\epsilon$$
>
> **Definition 2:**
>
> We say that $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is integrable if there exists an $L$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a tagged partition $P$ such that for any refinement $P*$ of $P$ we have that $$|S_{P*}(f)-L|<\epsilon$$
>
> If such an $L$ exists, we call it $\int _a^b f$ in both cases.

I was given this an exercise, I think the definitions are equivalent, it is easy to see that $1$ implies $2$, but the other implication seems very hard to solve. Is anyone familiar with a proof of this?

Comment: The Wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral (currently) does this by making a detour through the Darboux integral (not very elegantly however).

Comment: Let $P_1$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that it has one partition point $p_1$ which is a partition point of $P$. Let $P_2$ be a refinement of $P_1$ such that $P_2$ has $p_1$ and $p_2$ as partition points, where $p_2$ is also a partition point of $P$. In general, let $P_n$ have $n$ of the partition points from P. Then any $n\geq n_0$ (where $n_0$ is the number of partition points of $P$, we have that $|S_P(f)-L|<\epsilon$. We now have a sequence of partitions such that $||P_n||\to 0$. We now have one sequence, but we need it to hold for any sequence.

Comment: Not entirely sure that is something we can show easily.  I have also only seen it shown using upper and lower sums.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834341/72031