# Can one define "indefinite integral" without using the " primitive " concept, using the idea of " area function" ( or " accumulation function")?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, definition, indefinite-integrals

With a view at undertstanding better the ***FTC Part 1*** , I ask this question about the definition of " indefinite integral"

[image: calculus]

Comment: So... you have written a question as text, then taken a picture of it, then posted the picture?? Why not copy-and-paste the question text itself?

Comment: The FTC (as I know it) applies only to *continuous* functions.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: FTC is available for discontinuous functions also, but the formulation is much simpler if the function being integrated is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the meanings of "primitive", "indefinite integral", and "definite integral" (or more properly Riemann integral).

Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a function. A *primitive* of $f$ is another function $F:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ such that $F'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\in[a, b] $. *Anti-derivative* is synonymous with *primitive*.

Not every function possesses a primitive. However it is guaranteed via Fundamental theorem of calculus that continuous functions possess primitives. Two primitives of same function differ by a constant (this is a consequence of mean value theorem). Further the primitive of an elementary function need not be an elementary function.

*Indefinite integral* of $f$ represents the class of all primitives of $f$ (and as noted in last paragraph all of these differ by a constant). This is generally denoted by $\int f(x) \, dx$ and in general it is evaluated in the form $F(x) +C$ where $F$ is a primitive of $f$.

The *definite integral* or *Riemann integral* is another related and complicated beast. And moreover this is the central and more important idea in integral calculus. Primitive or indefinite integral is only a tool used to evaluate definite integral under certain circumstances. You should see the definition of Riemann integral in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834341/72031).

Now let's come back to your question. If $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ is a Riemann integrable function and $F:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ defined by $$F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ then $F$ is a related function which may or may not be the primitive of $f$. In fact it may happen that $f$ does not possess an anti-derivative / primitive. However FTC ensures that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ then the above function $F$ is a primitive of $f$ and we have $$\int f(x) \, dx=F(x) +C$$ You should observe that theory of integrals and related objects is much simpler if the function being integrated is continuous.